# Migration from Moss 2007 to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, migration

We have an application on Moss 2007 where good amount of customizations are present. Directly we cannot migrate to 2013. 
what will be best approach for this?
What all 3rd party tools are able to migrate nicely directly to 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Our organisation are currently in the planning stages of migration from Moss 2007 to 2013 Standard.

After numerous amounts of research we have uncovered that custom workflows and web parts can create issues when migrated into the 2013 platform due to the claims authentication in 2013 meaning it does not recognise your custom creations.

We are currently looking into a few recommended tools: Quest, Axceler, Sharegate, and Metavis.

Hope this helps!